# How do I pass a cell argument from a spreadsheet to a custum function as a range?

Tags: arguments, google-apps-script

I'm trying to get the following function to work by calling it from a spreadsheet cell:

```
=IsFormula(A1)

function IsFormula(aCell) {

  return cell.getFormula().length != 0
}
```

What should I do?

Dror

Comment: There is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206399/passing-cell-references-to-spreadsheet-functions).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206399/passing-cell-references-to-spreadsheet-functions

Answer (score 6):

Custom functions only have access to the cell's value, not the Range object itself. In your case, aCell would contain the value of the cell, which wouldn't work for your use case.