# How do I use an array as argument for my custom function in Google Apps Script in a spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a custom function in my google spreadsheet with the script editor.

I can't seem to allow the user to give the function an array as the argument.

My script works when I hardcode like this:

```
    var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("G2:j30").getValues();
```

What I want to do is pass the array as an argument:

```
   function arrayToList(chosenArray) {
        ...
        var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(chosenArray).getValues();
        ...
   }
```

Comment: How do you write your formula to use custom function. Do you use =arrayToList("G2:j30") or =arrayToList(G2:j30)

Comment: Actually I'd like the user to be able to choose the array so that's =arrayToList(G2:j30)

Comment: So in that case, your custom function simply becomes `function arrayToList(chosenArray) { var values = chosenArray; }`

Comment: This question may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206399/passing-cell-references-to-spreadsheet-functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now this functionality is not implemented in GAS. There are similar questions in SO ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206399/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371434/)). You can post a feature request to the [issue tracker](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).

Comment: This answer is obsolete since a while, it's even included on the official docs https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to pass an array as argument to a Google Sheets custom function

1. By using a range reference, like `A1:D5`. Usage: `=myCustomFunction(A1:D5)`.
2. By using the Google Sheets array notation like `{1,2;"Yellow","Orange"}`. Usage: `=myCustomFunction({1,2;"Yellow","Orange"})`.
   Note: If your spreadsheet is set to use comma as decimal separator use `/` as column separator

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions
- [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

Riku - Did you try calling your function as arrayToList(G2:j30)? I believe Apps Script will convert that selected range to a comma separated string (going left -> right and then top->down).

It wont be the same as a the Range object, but at least you can get a CSV string representation of the selected range and perhaps that is sufficient?