# How to convert formatted text to html tag in Google-apps-script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to convert a formatted text in a cell to html but I don't know how to read the format of the text.

Let's say that I have the following text in a cell:
A text with a **bold** word.

And I would like to convert it in an other cell to:
A text with a `<b>`bold`</b>` word.

How can I do that?

I didn't find anything useful in the Spreadsheet API to read format info...Does anyone have any tips?
Thanks.

EDIT: I've created a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6669). Please vote to have the feature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing font-weight of partial cell value in Google Sheet using Google App script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43465402/changing-font-weight-of-partial-cell-value-in-google-sheet-using-google-app-scri)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### My ***Google Script***

```
/**
 * Rich Text to HTML.
 * @param {string} qRange Input text.
 * @returns {string} Text as HTML.
 * @customfunction
 */
function RICHTEXT_TO_HTML(qRange) {
  var indexBool = false;
  var indexItalic = false;
  var indexUnderline = false;
  var indexStrikethrough = false;

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(qRange);
  var cell = range;
  var cellValue = cell.getRichTextValue();
  var txt = String(cell.getDisplayValue());
  var styles = cell.getTextStyles();
  var result = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    var style = cellValue.getTextStyle(i, i + 1);

    if (!indexStrikethrough && style.isStrikethrough()) {
      indexStrikethrough = true;
      result += '<strike>';
    } else if (indexStrikethrough && !style.isStrikethrough()) {
      indexStrikethrough = false;
      result += '</strike>';
    }

    if (!indexUnderline && style.isUnderline()) {
      indexUnderline = true;
      result += '<u>';
    } else if (indexUnderline && !style.isUnderline()) {
      indexUnderline = false;
      result += '</u>';
    }

    if (!indexBool && style.isBold()) {
      indexBool = true;
      result += '<b>';
    } else if (indexBool && !style.isBold()) {
      indexBool = false;
      result += '</b>';
    }

    if (!indexItalic && style.isItalic()) {
      indexItalic = true;
      result += '<i>';
    } else if (indexItalic && !style.isItalic()) {
      indexItalic = false;
      result += '</i>';
    }

    result += txt[i];
  }

  if (indexStrikethrough) {
    result += '</strike>';
  }

  if (indexUnderline) {
    result += '</u>';
  }

  if (indexBool) {
    result += '</b>';
  }

  if (indexItalic) {
    result += '</i>';
  }

  return result;
}
```

### Usage

- `A1` = "My *formatted* **example**!!!"
- `A2` = `=RICHTEXT_TO_HTML("A1")`
- `A2` Result = `My <i>formatted</i> <b>example</b>!!!`

### Working example

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mVvE8AdXYKSnaSIfRBrjfOeXxmTkVZovhguMZ3sc47M/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Do you think it's possible to get the color and the font?

Answer (score 2):

I went ahead and updated this idea to better reflect how we do this is 2021.

```
/**
 * @Author: Emma Sargent
 * Rich Text to HTML.
 * @param {Range} Google Sheets Range object
 * @returns {string} Text as HTML.
 * @customfunction
 */
function richTextToHtml(range) {
  const runs = range.getRichTextValue().getRuns();
  const formattedRuns = runs.map((run) => {
    const attr = {
      style: '',
    };
    const text = run.getText();
    const link = run.getLinkUrl();
    let parentTag = 'span';
    if (link) {
      parentTag = 'a';
      attr.href = link;
    }

    const style = run.getTextStyle();
    const styles = {
      'font-family': `'${style.getFontFamily()}'`,
      'font-size': `${style.getFontSize()}px`,
      color: style.getForegroundColor(),
    };
    attr.style = Object.entries(styles)
      .map(([key, val]) => `${key}: ${val}`)
      .join('; ');

    let tags = [];
    if (style.isBold()) {
      tags.push('b');
    }
    if (style.isItalic()) {
      tags.push('i');
    }
    if (style.isUnderline()) {
      tags.push('u');
    }
    if (style.isStrikethrough()) {
      tags.push('strike');
    }
    const headTags = tags.length ? `<${tags.join('><')}>` : '';
    const closeTags = tags.length ? `</${tags.join('></')}>` : '';
    const attrStr = Object.entries(attr)
      .map(([key, val]) => `${key}="${val}"`)
      .join(' ');

    const mainTag = `<${parentTag} ${attrStr}>${headTags}${text}${closeTags}</${parentTag}>`;
    const lineBreakFormattedStr = mainTag.replace(/[\r\n]/g, '<br>');
    return lineBreakFormattedStr;
  });

  return formattedRuns.join('');
}
```

And because someone emailed me and asked, here's a version that can be run as a custom function from the formula bar.

Spreadsheet formula: =richTextToHtml("YourSheetName!A1NotationRange")

```
function richTextToHtml(rangeStr) {
  let [sheetName, rangeName] = rangeStr.split("!");
  sheetName = sheetName.replaceAll("'",'');
  const range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName).getRange(rangeName);
  const runs = range.getRichTextValue().getRuns();
  const formattedRuns = runs.map((run) => {
    const attr = {
      style: '',
    };
    const text = run.getText();
    const link = run.getLinkUrl();
    let parentTag = 'span';
    if (link) {
      parentTag = 'a';
      attr.href = link;
    }

    const style = run.getTextStyle();
    const styles = {
      'font-family': `'${style.getFontFamily()}'`,
      'font-size': `${style.getFontSize()}px`,
      color: style.getForegroundColor(),
    };
    attr.style = Object.entries(styles)
      .map(([key, val]) => `${key}: ${val}`)
      .join('; ');

    let tags = [];
    if (style.isBold()) {
      tags.push('b');
    }
    if (style.isItalic()) {
      tags.push('i');
    }
    if (style.isUnderline()) {
      tags.push('u');
    }
    if (style.isStrikethrough()) {
      tags.push('strike');
    }
    const headTags = tags.length ? `<${tags.join('><')}>` : '';
    const closeTags = tags.length ? `</${tags.join('></')}>` : '';
    const attrStr = Object.entries(attr)
      .map(([key, val]) => `${key}="${val}"`)
      .join(' ');

    const mainTag = `<${parentTag} ${attrStr}>${headTags}${text}${closeTags}</${parentTag}>`;
    const lineBreakFormattedStr = mainTag.replace(/[\r\n]/g, '<br>');
    return lineBreakFormattedStr;
  });

  return formattedRuns.join('');
}
```

Demo sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X8I_lRXwoUXWRKb2hZPztDIPRs2nmXGtOuWmnrKWjAg/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Thank you **[Eduardo Cuomo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/717267/eduardo-cuomo)** for the answer. I wanted to add the code to get down to the bottom line with a little fix.

```
/**
 * @Author: Eduardo Cuomo 
 * Rich Text to HTML.
 * @param {string} qRange Input text.
 * @returns {string} Text as HTML.
 * @customfunction
 */

function RICHTEXT_TO_HTML(qRange) {
  var indexBool = false;
  var indexItalic = false;
  var indexUnderline = false;
  var indexStrikethrough = false;
  
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(qRange);
  var cell = range;
  var cellValue = cell.getRichTextValue();
  var txt = String(cell.getDisplayValue());
  var styles = cell.getTextStyles();
  var result = '';
  
  for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
    if(txt[i]=="\n"){
      result += '<br>';
    }else{
    var style = cellValue.getTextStyle(i, i + 1);
    
    if (!indexStrikethrough && style.isStrikethrough()) {
      indexStrikethrough = true;
      result += '<strike>';
    } else if (indexStrikethrough && !style.isStrikethrough()) {
      indexStrikethrough = false;
      result += '</strike>';
    }
    
    if (!indexUnderline && style.isUnderline()) {
      indexUnderline = true;
      result += '<u>';
    } else if (indexUnderline && !style.isUnderline()) {
      indexUnderline = false;
      result += '</u>';
    }
    
    if (!indexBool && style.isBold()) {
      indexBool = true;
      result += '<b>';
    } else if (indexBool && !style.isBold()) {
      indexBool = false;
      result += '</b>';
    }
    
    if (!indexItalic && style.isItalic()) {
      indexItalic = true;
      result += '<i>';
    } else if (indexItalic && !style.isItalic()) {
      indexItalic = false;
      result += '</i>';
    }
    
    result += txt[i];
    }
  }
  
  if (indexStrikethrough) {
    result += '</strike>';
  }
  
  if (indexUnderline) {
    result += '</u>';
  }
  
  if (indexBool) {
    result += '</b>';
  }
  
  if (indexItalic) {
    result += '</i>';
  }
  
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that creates more compact HTML (avoiding lots of spans setting styles):

```
function richTextToHtml(range) {
  let lastFont = null, lastSize = null, lastColor = null, lastLink = null;
  let parentClose = '';

  return range.getRichTextValue()
      .getRuns()
      .map(run => {
        const text = run.getText().replace(/[\r\n]/g, '<br>');
        const style = run.getTextStyle();
        const font = style.getFontFamily();
        const size = style.getFontSize();
        const color = style.getForegroundColor();
        const link = run.getLinkUrl();

        let mainTag = '';
        if (font !== lastFont || size !== lastSize || color !== lastColor || link !== lastLink) {
          mainTag += parentClose;
          mainTag += link ? `<a href="${link}"` : '<span';
          mainTag +=
              ` style="font-family:'${font}';font-size:${size}px;color:${color}">`;
          parentClose = link ? '</a>' : '</span>';
          lastFont = font;
          lastSize = size;
          lastColor = color;
          lastLink = link;
        }

        let closeTags = '';
        Object.entries({isBold: 'b', isItalic: 'i', isUnderline: 'u', isStrikethrough: 'strike'})
            .filter(([getter, tag]) => style[getter]())
            .forEach(([getter, tag]) => {
              mainTag += `<${tag}>`;
              closeTags = `</${tag}>${closeTags}`;
            });

        return `${mainTag}${text}${closeTags}`;
      })
      .join('') + parentClose;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to use getFontWeight properties of the Range to read these formating values. Example given here: [GAS-check-cell-format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15811805/google-spreadsheet-script-how-to-test-if-cell-is-bold)

Check Rucent88's answer.

Comment: Will this work if the cell has mixed formatting?  Such as  "This is my **cell** content" which can occur and is how I read the OP.

Comment: As @Karl_S  pointed out, this is not working with mixed format. I need to get start index and end index of format to be able to add html tag.

Comment: +1 As far as I know, it's not possible to get this kind of information for cells with mixed formatting. I searched extensively for this 1 month ago myself, without any luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've created a feature request for google here :https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=6669