# Changing font-weight of partial cell value in Google Sheet using Google App script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, text-formatting

To change the font weight of cell value in a Google trix using Google App script, I am using 'setFontWeight'. However, if I need to make a given word in bold, and not the entire cell value. Please see the expected result in image below -

[image]

How can I change font-weight of partial cell value in Google Sheet using Google App script ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According the the [yesterday's release notes](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/docs/release-notes#January_22_2019) (January 22, 2019), the Spreadsheet Service was extended to include new classes like [RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value) which makes now possible to set formatting for partial text.

Example from [Class RichTextValueBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value-builder)

```
// Creates a Rich Text value for the text "HelloWorld", with "Hello" bolded, and "World"
// italicized.
var bold = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setBold(true).build();
var italic = SpreadsheetApp.newTextStyle().setItalic(true).build();
var value = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue()
    .setText("HelloWorld")
    .setTextStyle(0, 5, bold)
    .setTextStyle(5, 10, italic)
    .build();
```