# Change hyperlink colors in Google Apps Script for Spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script, colors, hyperlink

**EDIT:** I have just spent an obscene amount of time trying to change the color for hyperlinks in Google Sheets, but it seems to be impossible.

I thought that by changing the [RichTextValue](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/rich-text-value) it could be possible to alter the TextStyle of hyperlinks. But it [doesn't seem to be possible to change only part of a cell's style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429645/making-bold-only-a-part-of-a-google-spreadsheets-cell).

**Question:** Am I right that it's impossible to change the style/color of hyperlinks in Google Sheets?

---

#### Original question

I want to change the default hyperlink color in a given Google Spreadsheet.

This is my attempt of coding a [Container-Bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound):

```
function changeLinkColor() {
    var app = SpreadsheetApp;
    var spreadsheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var linkColor = app.newColor().setRgbColor("#B4EBF7").build();
    spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTheme().setConcreteColor(app.ThemeColorType.HYPERLINK, linkColor);
}
```

I can see that it apparently changes  `Logger.log(spreadsheet.getSpreadsheetTheme().getConcreteColor(app.ThemeColorType.HYPERLINK)` to the desired value, but it makes no difference in my spreadsheet, hyperlinks are still blue.

I believe, however, that hyperlink colors in themes only work for reports, this is why it is making no difference for links inside cells.

Comment: Good news from 2019: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54337723/14265469

Comment: I did something like this -- get a style of characters from a cell https://stackoverflow.com/a/67624718/14265469 it works. I'm pretty sure it should work in both ways.

Comment: So it changes theme color, but links are not changed? Then it's a definitely Google Sheets bug, report here: https://issuetracker.google.com/

Comment: Of course it will change the color of the characters 'locally'. It has nothing to do with default settings for all links. Every new link will be blue.