# Accessing the Cell Coordinates in custom function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

Is there a way to access the cell coordinates (in A1 notation) of the cell that was passed in to my function?

For example, if my function is this

```
function displayA1Notation(myCell){
  return myCell.getA1Notation();
}
```

and I put the following in cell B4:

```
=displayA1Notation(C6)
```

I'm hoping to see this:

```
C6
```

But what I actually see is this:

```
Kansas
```

("Kansas" is the actual cell value of C6)

I know this seems easy... I'm just stuck in trying to get it to work.

Thanks~!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spreadsheet custom functions arguments contain only values pointed as arguments and not cell addresses. This fact not clear documented but there are a couple of similar questions here, for instance, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206399). There is a workaround by using the build-in function [ADDRESS](https://support.google.com/drive/bin/static.py?hl=en&topic=25273&page=table.cs). like in the following code

```
=myFunc(ADDRESS(ROW(F8), COLUMN(F8)))
```