# Addressing individual cells in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, cell, formula, custom-function

Not sure it can be done but here is the question. I have a sheets app with multiple sheets. Sheet 1 contains data as follows:

String Descriptor | Value 1 | Value 2

Sheet 2 is working formulas. Cell D37 in this example has a reference to 'Sheet1'!A14

On sheet 2, column E I'd like to reference back to 'Sheet1'!A16

If I pass the string value of "D37" I can find the cell and then manipulate things and return the proper data. I can't however get things to work when I try to get the cell address passed by the function I get "range not found" errors.

Sheet 2 reference is '=INDIRECT(myFunction(D37))

```
function myFunction(piNameCell) { //piNameCell has the reference to D37

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp;
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange(piNameCell);  // Like this it crashes
  //var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("D37");       //This works
  var sheetRef = sheet.getFormula();

  //remove the leading '=' sign
  sheetRef = sheetRef.substring(1);

  //find the !
  var bangIndex = sheetRef.indexOf("!");

  //change the column to 'E'
 sheetRef = sheetRef.substring(0,bangIndex+1) + "E" + sheetRef.substring(bangIndex+2)

  return sheetRef;
}
```

Comment: if you log `piNameCell`, what do you get?

Comment: The contents of the referenced cell, not the formula.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing cell references to spreadsheet functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206399/passing-cell-references-to-spreadsheet-functions)

Comment: Ruben, I read through that and tried many iterations. The proposed is 
`=GetFormula("C4")`Which puts a cell to reference as a string passed to the function GetFormula. This won't change the "C4" reference if the cell is copied to other cells.
`=GetFormula(C4)`
is what I'm looking for.

Comment: The getRange functions sort of works but only for a single use as you can't pass C4:C4 in one cell and reference C5:C5 in another.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said in your questions, you need to send the adress of the cell, not the content, but you don't want to send it as a string, because you want it to change if you move the formula. You have some options.

#### Get the cell coordinates

You could simply get the cell coordinates with the [ROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093316?hl=en) and [COLUMN](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093373) functions.
You'd have to change a little your function to use the coordinates instead. Your function call could look like that:

```
=INDIRECT(myFunction(ROW(D37), COLUMN(D37)));
```

And in your function you'd change the parameters and  the `getRange` function.

#### Use the cell coordinates to get the A1 notation

If you really want to send that A1 notation, you can do that with [ADDRESS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093308?hl=en).

```
=INDIRECT(myFunction(ADRESS(ROW(D37), COLUMN(D37))));
```

Comment: And this messy thing is the actual solution I contrived while trying to find something more elegant. 
`INDIRECT(fetchPrice(row(A4), CHAR(COLUMN(A4)+64)))`
Thank you for your input and support.