# Function not triggering

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I'm trying to use a function to get the hexadecimal code of the cell background and concatenate it with the text contained in the same cell.

i.e. in `sht1.cell(A1)` I type "Hello" with red background, I would have in  `sht2.cell(A1)` the following text: "[#FF0000]Hello"

I was trying this:

```
function getHexValue(range) {
return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(range).getBackground();
 }
```

but it doesn't always work, especially if I share the file. I tried to setup some triggers using edit, change or open events but id keeps not updating
 [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) is what i tried to do.

Any suggestion?

If I type: `=gethexvalue("A5")` I get the color code, if I type the formula to another cell or another sheet and I update the values or reload the sheet it doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom Functions and Recalculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25163243/custom-functions-and-recalculation)

Answer (score 0):

In your formula `=gethexvalue("A5")`, "A5" is text, not a dynamic range.

Read [How to pass a range into a custom function in Google Spreadsheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10629/how-to-pass-a-range-into-a-custom-function-in-google-spreadsheets) for a full discussion and 11 different answers. This is itself a possible duplicate of [passing cell references to spreadsheet functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12206399/passing-cell-references-to-spreadsheet-functions).

This `=getHexValue(ADDRESS(ROW(A1), COLUMN(A1)))&A1` is dynamic. It will return:

> "#ff0000Hello"

. If you want the hex in Uppercase, then use UPPER with getHexvalue.